# Take Picture with Camera and set on Image View not working in kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin, camera

I'm trying to create a camera picker functionality on the app and I face some of the methods of camera picture is deprecated so I trying to resolve the code and not using any depricated method.
First on manifest declares the permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

after that create a Camera intent:

```
private var imageStr:Uri?=null

val values = ContentValues()
values.put(Media.TITLE, "New Picture")
values.put(Media.DESCRIPTION, "From the Camera")
imageStr = requireActivity().contentResolver.insert(EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values)
// camera intent
val intent = Intent(ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageStr)
startForCameraResult.launch(intent)
```

and after that we get the value on startForCameraResult:

```
private val startForCameraResult = registerForActivityResult(StartActivityForResult()) {
    if (it.resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        profileImage.setImageURI(imageStr)
    }
}
```

Here is the code And The problem is I always get imagestr is null.
Please show me the right direction to handle this issue.
Thanks

Comment: For ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE intent u don't need Camera permission

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **`targetSdkVersion 29`** & **`compileSdkVersion 29`** you need to set `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` in application tag of **AndroidManifest.xml** file.